# Azure Function Event Hub Trigger one batch at a time

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am working on a project which gets change notifications through Event Hubs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery).

My Azure Function(Event Receiver) receives the events in batches. After receiving each batch, it processes the data (does a bit of work). The second batch updates the value set by the first batch.

The Event Hub has 3 partitions.

The problem arises when multiples batches arrives at the same time. . The second batch comes in before the first batch has updated the value.

Is there a way to receive only one batch at a time?

I am not bothered about the order of batches, but I want to get the next batch trigger only after the first batch is processed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partitions provide a degree of parallelism. You can run with a single-partition eventhub to avoid concurrency. Btw, why do you have that sequential processing requirement?

Comment: Is there any limitation when using single partition? Each message batch from Azure Hub updates some values in the database. So for example first batch updates values in database, when the second batch comes in that takes the values from database updated by first batch and after processing puts the new value to database.

Comment: Your design is pretty much bound to a single partition due to the sequential processing prerequisite. Do you have a single database or multiple? You can use a database name or some other database identifier as a partition key so that events for a database are always written to the same partition.

Try keeping per partition message volume below 1000 events/sec. Running with single partition should be alright as long as throughput limits are met.

Comment: I do not have a database in my design. How can I keep the messag/ partition below 1000? Is it possible in the event hub?

Comment: You are referring to database updates in your comment. I thought you were processing database change requests. Btw, 1000 events/sec/partition is a recommendation. You should be able to estimate whether you need to exceed that limit or not.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You [BrunoLucas-9843](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/3029870/brunolucas-9843.html) and [MughundhanRaveendran-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/mughundhanraveendran-msft/) for your valuable explanation and few workarounds. Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

> - Check out this [article](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428) regarding the configuration of **`maxBatchSize`** to pull a batch of 1 message for the function and the better way to reduce cost when passing single event vs ordered batch.

**Is there a way to make the event hub trigger wait until the first batch is processed?**

> - As soon you send the event and it hits the hub, the trigger function will pull that. There is also azure function parallelism that makes things more complicated.

> - Best I can think is to write a method like this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#receive-events  and use the Timer trigger to pull it every "X" minutes being X the average time it takes to process one whole batch (plus some extra time to make sure it clear it all).

I see that logic apps triggers for azure hub can pull a fixed number of events in one pull and wait:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs#trigger-polling-behavior

> Additionally you can try to set the cardinality to one in the function.json and test it at your end.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration

**Would it be possible to achieve the sequential processing using a Durable Function?**

> Yes, it is possible with durable and normal azure functions as well by leveraging the above suggested methods. With durable functins, you can use functions chaining : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#chaining.

> In durable functions, there is orchestrator and activity functions, if one of the activity function fails it will return error response to the orchestrator. The entire instance will not fail, you will be able to handle the exception